# If cell equals with a value in another cell then cellX

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

i am trying to use IF in the following arguement:

I have a sheet with a list of products next to it a list with manufacturer. In each product corresponds to a certain manufacturer of the list.

Now how i can tell a cell that if it found in the cell A1 on another sheet the a value from the list of products in the previous sheet to give me as a result the corresponded manufacturer.

I tried the following as a test:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B9;data!A:A);data!B:B;"product not found")
```

were B9 is the cell that i put the product manually, data!A:A is the range of the sheet that i have the list of the products and data!B:B is the list with the manufucturers.

The syntax i guess is ok since its working properly in excel but the thing is that i get always (product not found).

Could please someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just trying to do a lookup of manufacturer by product name? And if none found to report that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for either `Vlookup` (to find the corresponding manufacturer), or `countif` to say whether a manufacturer exists or not.

First: `Countif()`

```
 =if(Countif(data!A:A, B9)=0;"Product has mfg", "Product not found")
```

Second: `vlookup()`

```
=Vlookup(B9, Data!A:B, 2, false)
```

That `vlookup` will return the manufacturer, if one exists, if it doesn't then you will get an error. It does this by looking up the `b9` value in the first column of the range `DATA!A:B`. When it finds the value, it returns data from the second column (because we put `2` as the third parameter).

If you want to catch the error when the product doesn't have a manufacturer you can wrap the `vlookup` in an `iferror()` like:

```
=IfError(Vlookup(B9, Data!A:B, 2, false), "Product not found")
```

Comment: You are simply AWESOME... Super thanks.. I really apreciate it :)